# Reshape .nii images in such a way the depth must be first

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing, nifti

I am new to medical images and I encountered a format called **.nii/.nii.gz** The shape of the one file is: **(576, 576, 88)** The height and the width are 576, and the depth is 88.

But I want to reorient in this way **(88, 576, 576)**. ie the depth must be first. How can I achieve this in this situation using python?
I did as follow;

```
import nibabel as nib
img1 = nib.load("path_to_the_file/segmentation.nii.gz")
img1.shape
```

> > (576, 576, 88)

I did like this;

```
img1 = np.reshape(img1, (88, 576, 576))
```

But could not succeed.

Comment: Have a look here... https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html

Answer (score 1):

If you visualise your data as it is (with this initial shape (576, 576, 88)), you get slices on the sagittal plane (perpendicular to the left-right axis).

If you want images on the transverse plane (perpendicular to the cranio-caudal axis), you should do :

```py
img_transverse_plane = np.moveaxis(img1, -1, 0)
```

And on coronal plane :

```py
img_coronal_plane = np.moveaxis(img1, 0, -1)
```